# PostgeSQL: Verify user privileges

Tags: database, postgresql

How can I verify the privileges after granting the following to the `read_only_user`?

```
alter default privileges for role read_only_user grant all on tables to foodapp;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run this query to get default privileges:

```
SELECT
  defaclrole::regrole,
  defaclnamespace::regnamespace,
  CASE defaclobjtype
    WHEN 'r' THEN 'relation'
    WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence'
    WHEN 'f' THEN 'function'
    WHEN 'T' THEN 'type'
    WHEN 'n' THEN 'schema'
  END,
  (aclexplode(defaclacl)).*
FROM pg_default_acl;
```

And then add a WHERE clause for the user if you want to filter it.

Or in psql you can use:

```
\\ddp
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is seems interesting. I'm mentioning some ways below please read carefully and try it in your system. Some of them might help you. :)

You can do that by following:

### In One line

```
postgres=> \l
```

This command will display the information you're looking for.
like this.

```
postgres=> \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

The [docs on Privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-priv.html#PRIVILEGE-ABBREVS-TABLE) give an explanation of how to interpret the output. For specific privileges on a table of the current database, use `\z myTable`.

### Undercovers psql uses the bellow query when you issue `\du` command.

```
SELECT r.rolname, r.rolsuper, r.rolinherit,
  r.rolcreaterole, r.rolcreatedb, r.rolcanlogin,
  r.rolconnlimit, r.rolvaliduntil,
  ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid)
        WHERE m.member = r.oid) as memberof
, r.rolreplication
, r.rolbypassrls
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
WHERE r.rolname !~ '^pg_'
ORDER BY 1;
```

### In the case of the table.

```sql
    SELECT grantee, privilege_type 
    FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
    WHERE table_name='mytable'
```

This gives you this kind of output:

```
mail=# select grantee, privilege_type from information_schema.role_table_grants where table_name='aliases';
   grantee    |  privilege_type
--------------+-----------------
 mailreader   |  INSERT
 mailreader   |  SELECT
 mailreader   |  UPDATE
 mailreader   |  DELETE
 mailreader   |  TRUNCATE
 mailreader   |  REFERENCES
 mailreader   |  TRIGGER
(7 rows)

mail=#
```

Note that (at least under Postgres 9.4) the above will not work for materialized views.

### Using `psql` meta-commands:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Going over the page with Ctrl+F gives:

> `\ddp [ pattern ]`
> Lists default access privilege settings.
>
> `\dp [ pattern ]` Lists tables, views and sequences with their
> associated access privileges.

> `\l[+] [ pattern ]` List the databases in the server and show...
> access privileges.

Also mentioned above, but not found with word "privileges" on the manual page:

`\du+` for roles with login and `\dg+` for roles without - will have a filed `"Member of"` where you find roles granted to roles.

I deliberately skip function and language privileges here, found in `psql` manual as barely manipulated (and if you do use those privileges you won't come here for advice). same for user-defined types, domains, and so on - using "+" after the meta-command will show you privileges if applicable.

---

A little extreme way to check the privileges is dropping the user in the transaction, e.g.:

```
s=# begin; drop user x;
BEGIN
Time: 0.124 ms
ERROR:  role "x" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for type "SO dT"
privileges for sequence so
privileges for schema bin
privileges for table xx
privileges for table "csTest"
privileges for table tmp_x
privileges for table s1
privileges for table test
Time: 0.211 ms
s=# rollback;
ROLLBACK
Time: 0.150 ms
```

When the list is longer than N, (at least in 9.3), the warning with the list of privileges is collapsed, but you still can find it full in logs...